# Does "gay" necessarily mean male homosexual?

Tags: meaning, connotation, sexual-minorities

I was under the impression that *gay* always refers to a male homosexual, though sometimes I see this term used to describe female homosexuals (i.e. lesbians) as well. Is it correct usage? Does it depend on a dialect of English (American, Australian, etc.)?

Comment: Well, no: if you go far enough back (and it's not that far, really — 50 years ought to do it), *gay* just means *happy*.

Comment: yes it was such a beautiful normal word, that you could use everyday.

Comment: @t0ast3d I think it's *still* a "beautiful, normal word" you can use every day.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a gay transsexual woman?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37911/whats-a-gay-transsexual-woman). As the top answer there points out, this usage of *gay* isn't restricted to male homosexuals.

Comment: From *The Meaning of Liff*: "AINDERBY QUERNHOW (n.)
One who continually bemoans the 'loss' of the word 'gay' to the English language, even though they had never used the word in any context at all until they started complaining that they couldn't use it any more." Also, Fry and Laurie: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HtaPaQwSQPA

Comment: @ShreevatsaR - Your quotation needs a little flesh around it so one can be reasonably sure of your intent. I have certainly used "gay" long enough ago that its current major meaning had not been arrived at, and on occasion find I have used it in the "old" sense without thinking. This tendency is usually commented on with some alarm by hearers :-). The problem is that I tend to be effervescent or even scintillating and my expealidocious companions tend to feel that adamantine expressions of vivacious trepidation are outgrabe. | I do believe that Humpty Dumpty had something to say about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*[Gay](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/gay)* can refer to men and women who are sexually attracted to people of the same sex, though *[lesbian](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/lesbian)* only refers to women who are so.

Comment: +1. Absolutely right. I wonder if 'gaiety' will ever come to mean homosexualty?

Comment: That is true; but in many contexts it means males by default, as in *Madonna is very popular in the gay scene*, or *a gay accent* or just *gays*. As a pejorative adjective, it usually means effeminate, so male gay. It's complicated.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Jasper: In Salt Lake City, Utah, it is not uncommon to hear a woman describing herself as gay. So it can be non gender specific, just like the word *dude*.
It is OK to use it to exclaim to a woman, "dude, you rock," but if you were to say, "dude looks like a lady," that would be gender specific.

Comment: I'm surprised there are that many gay women in Salt Lake willing to talk about their sexuality...

Comment: http://www.futurescopes.com/lesbian-dating/2993/10-cities-large-lesbian-population

Salt Lake City is also listed as one of the more Bohemian cities in America.

Comment: Nice! I had no idea.

Answer (score 1):

At least in North America the term seems to be "LGBT" which does imply that they are reserving Gay for men only.

Or it could just be the natural tendancy for any 'protest' group to split into smaller and smaller sub-groups to differentiate themselves from the other identical groups  (especially the people's front of Judea!)

Comment: I don't claim to be an expert on the subject but the fact that homosexuals routinely refer to themselves as "gays and lesbians" would imply that "gay" is considered to refer to just males. Or maybe this is one of those cases where the male term when used as a collective can include the female. Such usage is generally considered unacceptable today on the grounds that it's sexist, but I presume homosexuals are exempt from any such criticism.

Comment: @Jay - at least in BE I think 'gay' would still be the general term outside the sexual politics industry. I suspect the others came about as a result of some heated meetings, although the meeting of the lesbian women's collective denying gay men entry on the grounds of sexism must have been interesting!

Comment: If you want to be totally inclusive, the broader term is "LGBTQIA" (lesbian, gay, bisexual, transgender, questioning, intersex, and asexual). The difficulty arises in that these initialisms aren't readily pronouncable. A common shorthand you do hear is "gay or straight," to mean homo- or heterosexual, implying that gay can include lesbian in standard discourse. If you are addressing a largely or significantly non-traditional audience, then LGBT, LBGQT, etc., may be preferred.

Comment: I believe the *People's Front of Judea* has now splintered into two bitterly opposed factions - *One Man's Front of Judea*, and *His Wife's Front of Judea*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Splitters !

Comment: I hear *His Wife* was pregnant before the schism, so I expect there'll be another faction soon!

Comment: @TheRaven I have also seen "LGBTQ". It was explained to me that the "Q" stood for "[Queer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queer)", a term intended to be a catchall for anyone whose non-heteronormative identity did not fit into the other categories.

Comment: What about LGBTCS - Lesbian,Gay,Bi,Trans,Computer Scientist?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the term has increasingly been used only for men.  It wouldn't be improper to use it to refer to women, but I've not heard the word used to refer to an individual woman in the last 10 years or so.  (For a group of mixed gender it's probably more acceptable.)