# How to specify a lover's gender

Tags: word-choice, sexual-minorities

Can you recognize that her lover is a woman from this part of the sentence?

> A doctor’s daughter hides her lover--

I am afraid you cannot, or you automatically think it is a man.

In my language, we use a single word for male or female lover, which is what got me into this situation.

Would the next sentence be more understandable?

> A doctor’s gay daughter hides her lover--

Would it be better if I use:

> A doctor’s daughter hides her gay lover–

Any other suggestions how to write this without that it is too much on the nose? Is there another, single word for a female lover instead of writing her female lover or gay daughter?

Comment: _...hides her **lesbian** lover_ would eliminate the ambiguity even further. I think that would read better, too.

Comment: @J.R. I know it is a matter of personal preference, but I think 'her lesbian lover' sounds awful. Syk, is there any reason you need to do this in just one word ie you cant change it to something like 'X hides Y, her lover.'

Comment: You definitely cannot tell from that part of the sentence, but presumably there is more to the sentence and the text it is a part of. Is it absolutely necessary to express that the lover is female at that exact point in the narrative? Otherwise you could say "girlfriend", depending on context and the connotations you're after.

Comment: "A doctor’s daughter hides her 'female' lover",  OR "A doctor’s daughter hides her girlfriend".

Comment: You say that "in [your] language you use one word for male or female lover". Isn't that also the case in English?

Comment: This question is currently unanswerable in the US.  Gender identity has gotten so complicated, that there are dozens of terms covering nuances of gender.  If you pick one, it likely will not be precise and will offend one or another grievance group, or most readers would not understand the correct precise term.  The safer practice is to treat gender as a personal choice that is nobody else's business and avoid trying to label it.  (Yes, gender is considered a choice and personal self-conceptualization that has little to do with a person's physical sex.)

Comment: I hope anyone will be able to see this. 
Thanks for all your effort. 
If I sum it up – “lover” is meant for a male. A “Gay lover” could be misinterpreted as a male. “Girlfriend” is a bit too vague in my case. It means multiple things and I have to be specific on this. This leaves me with “lesbian lover” and an extra punch that I will add later in the sentence. @J.R

Comment: I think you may be using "on the nose" incorrectly. I'm not sure what you think it means but the real meaning is simply "accurate" "or correct" so it doesn't make a lot of sense to say "too on the nose". https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-the-nose  I hope this helps.

Comment: Lover does not in any way mean male. A newspaper term is also *gal pal* for a female lover, not just friend.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any special vocabulary here. You can simply say:

> A doctor’s daughter hides her female lover ...

This is perfectly fine and idiomatic and is probably the closest to the meaning of the sentence in the Original Poster's language. One could easily also say:

- A doctor’s daughter hides her gay/lesbian lover ...

However, this overtly draws attention to the lover's sexual orientation in a way that the more neutral rendering with *female* does not.

Answer (score 1):

> A doctor’s daughter hides her lover

**Two suggestions**

1. Use the lover's name, e.g.

*A doctor’s daughter hides her lover, Janet ...*

2. Ask on [Writing Stack Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) where people are constantly dealing with the difficulties of writing about gender these days

---

P.S. You should avoid asking exactly the same question on two different Stack Exchanges, so you could perhaps delete this one, or phrase the new version more generally.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think the system permits easy deletion of a question once it has answers.

Comment: Of course the lover’s name is Sam :-)

Answer (score 0):

In English, the female equivalent of *gay* is *lesbian*. Well, it depends. If you're speaking informally then gay/lesbian could be both used. If speaking formally, you can use *homosexual*

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree that it's "more grammatically correct."

Comment: @J.R. "semantically correct" might be a better way of phrasing that ?

Comment: @RozennKeribin and even in that case I would say it's iffy at best. While gay is used more for homosexual men it is not exclusively so. See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47951/does-gay-necessarily-mean-male-homosexual

Comment: “Homosexual” is a word that I’d avoid outside the medical profession - and it doesn’t tell you anything about the gender so it’s useless for this question. And if the lover is bisexual, then “lesbian” would be wrong, but “bisexual” is also useless as far as the original question is concerned. “Female” seems to be easiest.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me that based on your comment about another language that what you're looking for is a way to communicate the gender  without creating a sentence that makes it transparent that the gender is somehow important or that the writer is purposefully attempting to communicate it.

I indeed agree with others that “female lover” would be the simplest answer, but like all the other answers in English that sentence implies that the lover's gender is relevant to the story, much like “rich lover” would.

There is no way to communicate the gender in English without that implication, as far as I know, as one can with words such as “brother” or “aunt”, which communicate gender without arousing that impression.